# ReactJS Array.push function not working in setState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I'm making a primitive quiz app with 3 questions so far, all true or false. In my `handleContinue` method there is a call to push the users input from a radio form into the `userAnswers` array. It works fine for the first run of `handleContinue`, after that it throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.userAnswers.push is not a function(…)`

```
import React from "react"

export default class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      questionNumber: 1,
      userAnswers: [],
      value: ''
    }

    this.handleContinue = this.handleContinue.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  //when Continue button is clicked
  handleContinue() {
    this.setState({
      //this push function throws error on 2nd go round
      userAnswers: this.state.userAnswers.push(this.state.value),
      questionNumber: this.state.questionNumber + 1
    //callback function for synchronicity
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.questionNumber > 3) {
        this.props.changeHeader(this.state.userAnswers.toString())
        this.props.unMount()
      } else {
        this.props.changeHeader("Question " + this.state.questionNumber)
      }
    })
    console.log(this.state.userAnswers)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    const questions = [
      "Blargh?",
      "blah blah blah?",
      "how many dogs?"
    ]
    return (
      <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <h1>{questions[this.state.questionNumber - 1]}</h1>
        <div class="radio">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="trueFalse" value="true" 
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>True
          </label><br/><br/>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="trueFalse" value="false" 
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>False
          </label>
          <hr/>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
          onClick={this.handleContinue}>Continue</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Do not modify state directly!](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) In general, try to [avoid mutation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data).

`Array.prototype.push()` *mutates* the array in-place. So essentially, when you `push` to an array inside `setState`, you mutate the original state by using `push`. And since `push` returns the new array length instead of the actual array, you're setting `this.state.userAnswers` to a numerical value, and this is why you're getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.userAnswers.push is not a function(…)` on the second run, because you can't `push` to a number.

You need to use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead. It doesn't mutate the original array, and returns a new array with the new concatenated elements. This is what you want to do inside `setState`. Your code should look something like this:

```
this.setState({
  userAnswers: this.state.userAnswers.concat(this.state.value),
  questionNumber: this.state.questionNumber + 1
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Array.push does not returns the new array. try using

```
this.state.userAnswers.concat([this.state.value])
```

this will return new userAnswers array

References: [array push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [array concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: This answer solves the problem but doesn't really explain what is happening. I recommend to take a look at my answer that explains the issue in more detail.

Answer (score 6):

You should treat the state object as immutable, however you need to re-create the array so its pointing to a new object, set the new item, then reset the state.

```
 handleContinue() {
    var newState = this.state.userAnswers.slice();
    newState.push(this.state.value);

    this.setState({
      //this push function throws error on 2nd go round
      userAnswers: newState,
      questionNumber: this.state.questionNumber + 1
    //callback function for synchronicity
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.questionNumber > 3) {
        this.props.changeHeader(this.state.userAnswers.toString())
        this.props.unMount()
      } else {
        this.props.changeHeader("Question " + this.state.questionNumber)
      }
    })
    console.log(this.state.userAnswers)
  }
```

Another alternative to the above solution is to use `.concat()`, since its returns a new array itself. Its equivalent to creating a new variable but is a much shorter code.

```
this.setState({
  userAnswers: this.state.userAnswers.concat(this.state.value),
  questionNumber: this.state.questionNumber + 1
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but it doesn't seem optimal to be declaring a new variable each time `handleContinue` is run. Though I could be wrong, thoughts?

Comment: You are right, it does cause waste of memory but its better than the potential race conditions that may arise if the state is mutated directly

Comment: This is not a very good answer. While it technically works, it's much shorter and clearer to just use `concat`, and [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) recommend doing so.

Comment: This does not work fine all the time. I just had an issue where the same approach was working in one component while not working on another one with same prop. 
It is better to use `concat` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended approach in later React versions is to use an updater function when modifying states to prevent race conditions:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  userAnswers: [...prevState.userAnswers, this.state.value] 
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution. This shoud work for splice and others too. Lets say that I have a state which is an array of cars:

```
this.state = {
  cars: ['BMW','AUDI','mercedes']
};
this.addState = this.addState.bind(this);
```

Now, addState is the methnod that i will use to add new items to my array. This should look like this:

```
  addState(){

let arr = this.state.cars;
arr.push('skoda');
this.setState({cars: arr});
}
```

I have found this solution thanks to duwalanise. All I had to do was to return the new array in order to push new items. I was facing this kind of issue for a lot of time. I will try more functions to see if it really works for all functions that normally won't. If anyone have a better idea how to achieve this with a cleaner code, please feel free to reply to my post.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to mutate your state when you want to push something to it is to do the following. Let's say we have defined a state as such:

```
const [state, setState] = useState([])
```

Now we want to push the following object into the state array. We use the concat method to achieve this operation as such:

```
let object = {a: '1', b:'2', c:'3'}
```

Now to push this object into the state array, you do the following:

```
setState(state => state.concat(object))
```

You will see that your state is populated with the object.
The reason why concat works but push doesn't is because of the following

```
Array.prototype.push() adds an element into original array and returns an integer which is its new array length.



Array.prototype.concat() returns a new array with concatenated element without even touching in original array. It's a shallow copy.
```