# React - how to add new element in array type state?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I have refereed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052598/reactjs-array-push-function-not-working-in-setstate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505064/react-js-what-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-value-to-an-array-in-state) link to find solution but none of them work for me.

I have decleared state with array type and other state with null.

```
this.state = {  from: '', to: '',journeyDate: '',searchDetails: [] }
```

As user fill up search form with source city , destination city and journey date I set these state like below .

```
    let from = this.state.from;
    let to = this.state.to;
    let journeyDate = moment(this.state.journeyDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

final step to push these all variables into searchDetails array state. for that I have tried below options but none of them worked.

> OPTION 1

```
this.setState({ searchDetails: [...this.state.searchDetails, from] });
```

> OPTION 2

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
            searchDetails: [...prevState.searchDetails, from]
        }))
```

> OPTION 3

```
let newState = this.state.searchDetails.slice();
        newState.push(from);

        this.setState({
            searchDetails: newState
        });
      console.log('final state is : ' + this.state.searchDetails);
```

every time console log remains empty.

any advice ?

Comment: Can you provide complete code of your component ? Also, did you check and from, to and journeyDate have values?  I see you taking these values from state and updating the array (searchDetails), but where you are pushing values into state ?

Comment: @Umesh from , to and journeyDate state are set perfectly and I have console them too. So there is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
this.setState({
    searchDetails: newState // use any of your 3 methods to set state
},() => {
     console.log('final state is : ' + this.state.searchDetails);
});
```

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later.
>
> This makes reading this.state
> right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.
>
> Instead, use
> componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
> callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
> has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
> state, read about the updater argument below.

For More Detail, Please read : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: on form submit I want to set searchDetails state and want to access this set in next page as a this.props.searchDetails. so my question is can I get value of searchDetails state in next page as a this.props.searchDetails ?

Comment: Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455200/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-another-in-react-or-react-redux

Answer (score 2):

Actually `setState` is an asynchronous method. That means right after writing `setState`, you cannot expect the state to be changed immediately. So `console.log` right after `setState` may show you last `state` instead of new state. If you want to log the updated state then use the callback of `setState` which is called when state is updated like this

```
this.setState({ searchDetails: [...this.state.searchDetails, from] }, () => { 
    console.log(this.state.searchDetails)
});
```