# setState not working in setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the value of `stateValue` with the value of `i` in `setInterval` but it changes only the value of `i` and doesn't update the  `stateValue` in `setInterval`.

```
fun1 = () => {
  let i = 0;
  let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("i:", i);
    this.setState({
      stateValue: i
    });

    i = i + 1;
    if (i === 3) {
      i = 0;
    }
    console.log("stateValue:", this.state.stateValue);
  }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: check this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385492/react-how-to-add-new-element-in-array-type-state?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: setState is an asynchronous method. That means right after writing setState, you cannot expect the state to be changed immediately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[FROM DOC :](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)**

> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state`
>   right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater,
>   callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the `updater` argument below.

You should use this to get the immidiate state update value:

```
this.setState({
    stateValue: i
},() => {
    console.log("stateValue:", this.state.stateValue);
});
```

Comment: thank you sir its working now