# Push method in React Hooks (useState)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How to push element inside useState array React hook?
Is that as an old method in react state? Or something new?

E.g. [setState push example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052598/reactjs-array-push-function-not-working-in-setstate) ?

Answer (score 792, accepted):

When you use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), you can get an update method for the state item:

```
const [theArray, setTheArray] = useState(initialArray);
```

then, when you want to add a new element, you use that function and pass in the new array or a function that will create the new array. Normally the latter, since state updates are asynchronous and sometimes batched:

```
setTheArray(oldArray => [...oldArray, newElement]);
```

Sometimes you can get away without using that callback form, if you **only** update the array in handlers for certain specific user events like `click` (but not like `mousemove`):

```
setTheArray([...theArray, newElement]);
```

The events for which React ensures that rendering is flushed are the "discrete events" listed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/events/plugins/SimpleEventPlugin.js).

Live Example (passing a callback into `setTheArray`):

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;
function Example() {
    const [theArray, setTheArray] = useState([]);
    const addEntryClick = () => {
        setTheArray(oldArray => [...oldArray, `Entry ${oldArray.length}`]);
    };
    return [
        <input type="button" onClick={addEntryClick} value="Add" />,
        <div>{theArray.map(entry =>
          <div>{entry}</div>
        )}
        </div>
    ];
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Because the only update to `theArray` in there is the one in a `click` event (one of the "discrete" events), I could get away with a direct update in `addEntry`:

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;
function Example() {
    const [theArray, setTheArray] = useState([]);
    const addEntryClick = () => {
        setTheArray([...theArray, `Entry ${theArray.length}`]);
    };
    return [
        <input type="button" onClick={addEntryClick} value="Add" />,
        <div>{theArray.map(entry =>
          <div>{entry}</div>
        )}
        </div>
    ];
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ...and try `setTheArray(currentArray => [...currentArray, newElement])` if the above does not work. Most likely in `useEffect(...theArray..., [])`, it's important to realize that `theArray` is a constant, so [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) are needed for values from future renders

Comment: @Aprillion - Not quite sure what you're saying with that `useEffect` example...?

Comment: If the `useEffect` has an empty dependency list `[]`, it will be executed only during the first render. So the value of `theArray` inside the effect will always be `initialArray`. In situations where `setTheArray([...initialArray, newElement])` would not make sense, and when `theArray` constant will always equal to `initialValue`, then functional updates are needed.

Comment: @Aprillion - I'm afraid I'm still not getting it, possibly being a bit dense. :-) Why would you need an effect with just the *initial* array value? (I mean, there may be an infrequent use case, but...) And even if you do, what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without incurring the  overhead of copying the array each time?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Officially, no. :-) You can't directly modify objects held in React state. With **really, really thorough testing** that you repeat on each React minor release, you might get away with a direct update followed by A) a call to [`forceUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) (in a class component), or B) changing some other state member (to trigger a re-render). But any component using the array that optimizes by not re-rendering when the array doesn't change ([`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), ...

Comment: ...[`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), etc.) will be confused by it. Or you could play games with a `Proxy` (where you replace the `Proxy` rather than copying the array), and provide the proxy to anything else that uses it. I wouldn't be surprised if that ended up being more overhead, rather than less, than just copying the array.

Answer (score 125):

To expand a little further,
here are some common examples. Starting with:

```
const [theArray, setTheArray] = useState(initialArray);
const [theObject, setTheObject] = useState(initialObject);
```

Push element at end of array

```
setTheArray(prevArray => [...prevArray, newValue])
```

Push/update element at end of object

```
setTheObject(prevState => ({ ...prevState, currentOrNewKey: newValue}));
```

Push/update element at end of array of objects

```
setTheArray(prevState => [...prevState, {currentOrNewKey: newValue}]);
```

Push element at end of object of arrays

```
let specificArrayInObject = theObject.array.slice();
specificArrayInObject.push(newValue);
const newObj = { ...theObject, [event.target.name]: specificArrayInObject };
theObject(newObj);
```

Here are some working examples too.
[https://codesandbox.io/s/reacthooks-push-r991u](https://codesandbox.io/s/reacthooks-push-k9k5i?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: The problem is that setTheArray is not updating immediatly the array, inside component handleMethod you can't call theArray value.

Answer (score 28):

You can append array of Data at the end of custom state:

```
  const [vehicleData, setVehicleData] = React.useState<any[]>([]);
  setVehicleData(old => [...old, ...newArrayData]);
```

For example, In below, you appear an example of axios:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        {
          url: `http://localhost:4000/api/vehicle?page=${page + 1}&pageSize=10`,
          method: 'get',
        }
      );
      setVehicleData(old => [...old, ...result.data.data]);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [page]);
```

Answer (score 17):

Most recommended method is using wrapper function and spread operator together. For example, if you have initialized a state called `name` like this,

`const [names, setNames] =  useState([])`

You can push to this array like this,

```
setNames(names => [...names, newName])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: trigger setName(names => [...names, "newval"])  onChange, and console.log(names) returns []. Why isn't updated right away?

Answer (score 7):

```
// Save search term state to React Hooks with spread operator and wrapper function

// Using .concat(), no wrapper function (not recommended)
setSearches(searches.concat(query))

// Using .concat(), wrapper function (recommended)
setSearches(searches => searches.concat(query))

// Spread operator, no wrapper function (not recommended)
setSearches([...searches, query])

// Spread operator, wrapper function (recommended)
setSearches(searches => [...searches, query])
```

> https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-add-to-an-array-in-react-state-3d08ddb2e1dc

Answer (score 2):

**`setTheArray([...theArray, newElement]);`** is the simplest answer but be careful for the mutation of items in **theArray**. Use deep cloning of array items.

Comment: The deep cloning you mention, does it mean receive as objA. UseState and concat the objA with objB? Same as this link? https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kahsing/8b6701d4678aaedc71b3731bffbdea81/raw/be899c14b11587f0bcd3c6c25f7698044b60e61e/ItemList.js

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above methods for pushing an object into an array of objects in useState but had the following error when using **TypeScript**:

> Type 'TxBacklog[] | undefined' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)

The setup for the tsconfig.json was apparently right:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es6",
   "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "es6",
],
```

This workaround solved the problem (my sample code):

Interface:

```
   interface TxBacklog {
      status: string,
      txHash: string,
   }
```

State variable:

```
    const [txBacklog, setTxBacklog] = React.useState<TxBacklog[]>();
```

Push new object into array:

```
    // Define new object to be added
    const newTx = {
       txHash: '0x368eb7269eb88ba86..',
       status: 'pending'
    };
    // Push new object into array
    (txBacklog) 
       ? setTxBacklog(prevState => [ ...prevState!, newTx ])
       : setTxBacklog([newTx]);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to push after specific index you can do as below:

```
   const handleAddAfterIndex = index => {
       setTheArray(oldItems => {
            const copyItems = [...oldItems];
            const finalItems = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < copyItems.length; i += 1) {
                if (i === index) {
                    finalItems.push(copyItems[i]);
                    finalItems.push(newItem);
                } else {
                    finalItems.push(copyItems[i]);
                }
            }
            return finalItems;
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you have this state :

```
const [array, set_array] = useState([]);
```

then in your function push to your array like this :

```
set_array([...array, new_array]);
```