# how to set state array using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, setstate

Thanks in advance.
I have a state array as below.

I need to add an item to state array, I came across that we need not do state mutation. How do i set state with prevState.

```
const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState(
        [
            {
                _id: 12,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                text: 'All good',
                user: {
                    _id: 1,
                    name: 'Sian Pol',
                }
            },
            {
                _id: 21,
                createdAt: "2019-11-10 22:21",
                text: 'Hello user',
                user: {
                    _id: 2,
                    name: 'User New'
                }
            }]
    )
```

How to to i call the set State to append this state array.

Something like this?

```
setMessages(previousState => ({...stat
```

Can anyone help me in getting the above line code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push method in React Hooks (useState)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676966/push-method-in-react-hooks-usestate)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To insert new element at the end of the list

```
const addMessage = (newMessage) => setMessages(oldMessages => [...oldMessages, newMessage])
```

To insert new element at the begining of the list

```
const addMessage = (newMessage) => setMessages(oldMessages => [newMessage, ...oldMessages])
```

Comment: In my case, using push was an issue because I was returning the result from the push itself, which returns the new length of the array, not the array itself. `setSelectedList(prevState => prevState.push(val))` will set the state object to the length of the array, in other words.

Answer (score 15):

More readable and cleaner solution it would be:

Create a variable that holds a copy of the actual state:

**If state is an array and you need to add an element in it**

```
const newState = [...messages, 'Hi buddy'];
setMessages(newState);
 
or

setMessages(prevState => [...prevState, "Hi Buddy"]);
```

**If state is an object and you need to update a property in it**

```
const newState = Object.assign({}, message, {name: 'Michael Scott'});
setMessages(newState);

or

setMessages(prevState => {...prevState, name: "Michael Scott" });
```

Comment: I think this will mutate the state.

Comment: It will not for sure

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash That is what the ...spread operator does, make a copy, thus no mutation happens

Comment: What are the consequences of one on another? Are both same performance wise?

Answer (score 1):

Your state is an array so you will need to spread your previous state into a new array and add the new message using `[...prevState, newMessage]`

What you try to do is return an object, because `{}` is a code block so you need to wrap it inside `()` if you return an object which is what you are trying to do

```js
setMessages(prevState => [...prevState, newMessage])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setMessages(prevState => [...prevState, newMessage])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need to use the prevState, you could just do:

```
setMessages([...messages, newMessage])
```