# React Native Firebase fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch data from firebase.
I want to push the values in an array and map through it in a view.
The only problem is that i can see the values in my array but not outside the .then function.

```
const dataArray = []
  
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("Challenges/Day")
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        dataArray.push(child.val());
      });
      console.log(dataArray)
    });


  return (
    <View style={styles.text}>
      {dataArray.map((data) => {
        <Text>{data}</Text>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
```

if i console log it then the output is :
Array [
"eat",
"sleep",
]
But outside it's function my array is empty.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is console.log() is getting executed even before the data is returned from the firebase as response. When the request is made it takes sometime (say 1 sec) to return the response, but in the meantime the control executes the next line which is console.log(). When this line is executed, the value of **dataArray=[]** at that amoment. So for your case it is best to keep **dataArray** as **state variable**, so when the response is returned you can set the value of the dataArray which will re-render your component, thus displaying its return value.

```
const [dataArray,setDataArray] = useState([])
  
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("Challenges/Day")
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      let tempArray=[];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        tempArray.push(child.val());
      }
      setDataArray(tempArray);
      );
      console.log(dataArray)
    });


  return (
    <View style={styles.text}>
      {dataArray.map((data) => {
        <Text>{data}</Text>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

It's due to 2 issues you are facing.

1. asynchrounous - means what you are seeing in UI is the [] before firebase is executed.
2. state update - there were no state updated, hence even after the variable change occurred in firebase, the UI is not updated. Any normal variable changes will not re-render the UI, only a *state change will trigger a re-render in React.

What you can do.

```
const [dataArray, setDataArray] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
   firebase
   .database()
   .ref("Challenges/Day")
   .once("value")
   .then((snapshot) => {
     snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    //call an update to the array.
    //setDataArray((oldDataArray) => oldDataArray.push(child.val()))
      setDataArray((oldDataArray) => [...oldDataArray, child.val()])
    });
      console.log(dataArray)
    });
}, []); //will only initialize once(on mount). Putting outside will get called again and again when state change.

return (
<View style={styles.text}>
  {dataArray.map((data) => {
    <Text>{data}</Text>;
  })}
</View>
);
```

Comment: then i get an error: TypeError: oldDataArray.push is not a function. (In 'oldDataArray.push(child.val())', 'oldDataArray.push' is undefined)]

Comment: my mistake,
suppose to be:

setDataArray((oldDataArray) => [...oldDataArray, child.val()]);

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100863/how-to-set-state-array-using-react-hooks

Comment: the only problem now is that i get the same value a hundred times. But i'm getting close. Thank you!

Comment: make sense, seems your database got initialized again and again. I suggest this change..see the modified.