# Create a single state array for all items of flatlist. (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a react native app, where I am using `FlatList` for some purpose. I have a list of items displayed through the `FlatList`. That FlatList returns a component that I have made the finally displays the items.

```
const [allAmen , setAllAmen] = useState({});
let arr = [];
const test = (uName) => {
         setAllAmen({...allAmen , "name" : uName })
}
arr.push(allAmen);
console.log(arr);

<FlatList 
    data={amens}
    keyExtractor={(amen) => amen.id}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
             test(item.name)
          }}
        >
               <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    }}
/>
```

When I run this and press on one of the items of the list, it set the object in allAmen and pushes in arr. But if I press another item, it makes a new array and gives the result. S0 for every item of the flatlist a new state object and the array is created and the result is pushed in for a different array for each item. So if I have the following :

Flatlist ->

Candy Bar
White Chocolate Bar
Red Velvet

and I press on first I get -> `[{"name": Candy Bar}]` but then if I press on White Chocolate Bar it gives, `[{"name" : White Chocolate Bar }]` and same for Red Velvet.

What I want is if I press first i get -> [{"name" : Candy Bar}] then if I press second and after that third-> 
`[{"name" : Candy Bar} , {"name" : White Chocolate Bar}, { "name" : Red Velvet}]`.

But it is running individually for every list. Can someone help me on how to do this? I am fairly new to react native and javascript and running it to a lot of doubts. Tried to find it on StackOverflow and internet but could not get anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const newValue = {"name" : uName};
setAllAmen(prevArray => [...prevArray, newValue])
```

See more explanations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58556049/905494
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677026/905494

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks for the links as well. The explanation made it very easy to understand what was happening.  Cheers.