# Append new array of object to the current object of state React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my current data

```
const [propertyData, setPropertyData] = useState({
    propertyName: '',
    contacts: [
     {
       contactName: 'Person1',
       contactNumber: 'Number1',
     },
     {
       contactName: 'Person2',
       contactNumber: 'Number2',
     },
    ]
})
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to add another object to `contacts` like this

```
contacts: [
     {
       contactName: 'Person1',
       contactNumber: 'Number1',
     },
     {
       contactName: 'Person2',
       contactNumber: 'Number2',
     },
     {
       contactName: 'Person3',
       contactNumber: 'Number3',
     },
    ]
```

What I'm doing is this

```
setPropertyData({
  ...propertyData,
  contacts: [{ ...propertyData.contacts, contactPerson: 'Person3', contactNumber: 'Number3', }]
})
```

But what it does is it's updating the current data with just the new one without the old one like this

```
contacts: [
     {
       contactName: 'Person3',
       contactNumber: 'Number3',
     },
    ]
```

I'm kind of always confused using the spread operator especially if it's an array or an object I have to to append to. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Try `contacts: [...propertyData.contacts, {contactPerson: 'Person3', contactNumber: 'Number3'}]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push method in React Hooks (useState)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676966/push-method-in-react-hooks-usestate)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax to add a new object to your array of objects :

```
setPropertyData({
  ...propertyData,
  contacts: [...propertyData.contacts, { contactPerson: 'Person3', contactNumber: 
            'Number3' }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setPropertyData({
  ...propertyData,
  contacts: [...propertyData.contacts, {contactPerson: 'Person3', contactNumber: 'Number3'}]
})
```