# Adding an element to an existing array in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

So I have this state variable:

```
const [Class, setClass] = useState({ Teacher: "John Fartsalot", Year: 2021, Students: [] });
```

and I have a:

```
ver studentObject
```

I want to push the `studentObject` into the `Students` array dynamically using `setClass`.

I came across this post: [Push method in React Hooks (useState)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676966/push-method-in-react-hooks-usestate) but it seems to be relevant only when there's just the list in there.

What is the correct way to do so in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could spread the existing `Class` into a new object, and then spread the new `students` array into that new object as well, it would be better to follow the convention and *separate out* the state variables (as React recommends), and to not use `Class` as a variable name (it's very close to the reserved word `class`). Consider:

```
const [teacher, setTeacher] = useState('John Fartsalot');
const [year, setYear] = useState(2021);
const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
```

Then to add to the students array, do

```
setStudents([...students, studentObject]);
```

Or, if `students` happens to be in a stale closure at this point, then

```
setStudents(students => [...students, studentObject]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach seems to work but unfortunately I may need to alter an existing student list later on from the database. Is there a way to insert it directly? I will change the name of the Class state either way. Something like this maybe?

setClassData(ClassData => ({ ...ClassData, Students: *some-code* }))

Comment: You should really separate out the separate types of state into different state variables. If you get a new student list from the DB, just call `setStudents` with it. `setStudents(studentsFromDB)`

Answer (score 1):

This is correct way to add:

```
setStudents(students => [...students, studentObject]);
```