# How to push setState array to data?

Tags: react-native

I am  new Comer to react native.
I need to,
How to push setState array to new data?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvtr4.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvtr4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setCurrencies(prevCurrencies => [...prevCurrencies, 'UAH', 'PLN'])`

More info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677026/10617148

Comment: ERROR  Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. I have this error

Comment: I guess you put this code in "render" scope (it's meaning code before return in component). Please create handler function and pass into Button component as example: in render `const handlePress = () => { setCurrencies(prevCurrencies => [...prevCurrencies, 'UAH', 'PLN']) }`, after return `<Button title="Press" onPress={handlePress} />` Also you can see more example in here https://reactnative.dev/docs/button