# useState Array. ERROR Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I am having an array stored in a state. When I try to push new data to array, it is returning this error:
`Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

This is the code I am using:

```
const [currencies,setCurrencies] = useState(['USD', 'AUD', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'EURP']); 
setCurrencies(currencies => [...currencies, 'NSD', 'PLN']);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full code? Or mention where you are calling the setCurrencies function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to push setState array to data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67754822/how-to-push-setstate-array-to-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try doing:

```js
setCurrencies([...currencies, 'NSD', 'PLN']);
```