# How to push to state in React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to update the state with an array. But I need to keep the existing information in the array and just push more information into it.

Here is my state:

```js
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
```

This is my function I am calling for the onClick event listener

```js
const filteredByCategory = (event, category, products) => {
  const element = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
  
  if (element.checked) {
    const productsToAdd = products.filter(
      (product) => product.category === category
    );
    
    setFilteredProducts((currentFilteredProducts) => [
      ...currentFilteredProducts,
      ...productsToAdd,
    ]);
    
    dispatch({
      type: "PRODUCTS_FILTERED",
      payload: filteredProducts,
    });
  } else {
    let removedCheckedProducts = filteredProducts.filter((product) => {
      return product.category !== category;
    });
    
    setFilteredProducts(removedCheckedProducts);
    
    if (removedCheckedProducts.length >= 1) {
      dispatch({
        type: "PRODUCTS_FILTERED",
        payload: removedCheckedProducts,
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: "PRODUCTS_FILTERED",
        payload: allProducts,
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push method in React Hooks (useState)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676966/push-method-in-react-hooks-usestate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that you expect the `filteredProducts` state value to reflect your changes right after `setFilteredProducts`:

```
setFilteredProducts((currentFilteredProducts) => [
    ...currentFilteredProducts,
    ...productsToAdd,
]);
dispatch({
    type: "PRODUCTS_FILTERED",
    payload: filteredProducts,
});
```

Unfortunately, that's not how state updates work. The `set*` function simply queues the update for the next render, but does not immediately update the state.

You could maintain a local variable to pass the update both into the local state and into the Redux store:

```
const updatedProducts = [
    ...filteredProducts,
    ...productsToAdd,
];
setFilteredProducts(updatedProducts);
dispatch({
    type: "PRODUCTS_FILTERED",
    payload: updatedProducts,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

digitalbreed identified the race condition correctly in his answer. An example  of this behavior can be seen in this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-mountain-m9234?file=/src/App.js) by viewing the  console after clicking the `addProduct` button