# Correctly push element to array state with async function

Tags: reactjs

I found a solution to push elements to an array state ([Push method in React Hooks (useState)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676966/push-method-in-react-hooks-usestate))
But as you see below, `setTheArray` is inside a callback. So the order of `theArray` depend of the callback time.
**How to preserve order of `theArray` based on `service_months`'s order ?**

```js
useEffect(() => {
  for (const service_month of service_months) {
    GET(`/api/report/${props.user_id}`, service_month, resp => {
      setTheArray(oldArray => [...oldArray, resp.data])
    })
  }
}, [service_months])
```

Comment: You might be able to immediately insert a placeholder element and then replace it with the real value once it arrives, though there may be better approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to convert the callback to a `Promise` and also minimise state changes on every report using something like this:

```
const GETAsync = (URL, val) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    GET(URL, val, (resp) => {
      resolve(resp.data)
    })
  })
}

useEffect(() => {
async function updateState() {
  const data = await Promise.all(
    service_months.map((service_month) =>
      GETAsync(`/api/report/${props.user_id}`, service_month)
    )
  )

  setTheArray((oldArray) => [...oldArray, ...data])
}

updateState()
}, [service_months])
```