# React initial state as empty array question?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const object1 = {name: "David", id=5};
```

If I use the initial state as an empty array:

```
const [relatedPosts, setRelatedPosts] = useState([])
```

and then I use `setRelatedPosts(object1)` will the `relatedPosts` become an array with object1 inside it? Or it will be just object1 and React ignores the empty array set as initial value.

Comment: it replaces the state, you have to build a new array when setting the state.

Comment: On the first render, it will be an empty array. When you call setRelatedPosts(object1), it will rerender with just that object as the state (the array is gone)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push method in React Hooks (useState)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676966/push-method-in-react-hooks-usestate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I have understood that you are asking if the data type for the state will remain `array` or not!? Well the answer is that `relatedPost` will be set to as an `object` if set to `relatedPosts=object1` not `relatedPosts=[object1]`

react will ignore the initial value ([])

Comment: why does react ignore the value [] ?

Comment: It's cause here it is been set as an object data structure. We use typescript to counter such problems, so when our code is typed and if we want to keep it as an array type, we'll have to set our state type as an array and the default type as null

`const [relatedPosts, setRelatedPosts] = useState<Record<string, string | number>[] | null>(null)`

so now it is typed, if we set it as an object, The IDE that supports typescript will give error on compile time that `object` type cannot be set to `Record<string, string | number>[] | null`

Answer (score 0):

If you declared:

`const [relatedPosts, setRelatedPosts] = useState([])`
& then do `setRelatedPosts(object1)`, then the value of variable `relatedPosts` becomes `object1`: it is that simple.

See [declaring a state variable](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable)

Comment: I meant does relatedPosts become relatedPosts=[ object1 ]  or relatedPosts=object1

Comment: It just becomes `object1`, (i.e., `relatedPosts=object1`)

Answer (score 0):

Please describe the question. What you actually need.

I guess your problem and try to solve.

```
  const [relatedPosts, setRelatedPosts] = useState([]);

  const object1 = {name: "David", id:5}; //{name: "David", id=5} use ':' instead '=' when in object

  setRelatedPosts([object1, ...relatedPosts]);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, my question was  I meant does relatedPosts become relatedPosts=[ object1 ]  or relatedPosts=object1     Basically does object1 get pushed to the initial empty array or the initial empty array gets removed and it becomes just object1