# Error saving to hook array: object is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

everyone.
I'm trying to store an object into a hook array after the user clicks a button for a product.
However, I keep getting an: object is not iterable error.

The Main Part:

```
let shoppingArray = [];
const shopping = (item) => {
 shoppingArray.push(item);
 console.log(shoppingArray);
 setShoppingBag(...shoppingBag, shoppingArray);
};

...

 <ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon className="icons" onClick={() => shopping(item)}></ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon>
```

Error code:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

[image]

**UPDATE**

Why doesn't this work here?

```
const [shoppingBag, setShoppingBag] = React.useState([]);


 const shopping = (item) => {
  setShoppingBag(...shoppingBag, item);
};
```

Comment: I think this link will answer your question as well as you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676966/push-method-in-react-hooks-usestate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
setShoppingBag([...shoppingBag, ...shoppingArray]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing array [] in the function call. `setShoppingBag(...shoppingBag, shoppingArray);` should be `setShoppingBag([...shoppingBag, shoppingArray]);`