# Array.map() method not printing list in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update a list using Firebase in `useEffect()` and then print it using `Array.map()` method but it's not working.

Full code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";

export default function Home({ navigation }) {

    let [list, setList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const dbref = ref(db, localStorage.getItem('uid'));
    onValue(dbref, (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            list.push({
                id: list.length + 1,
                amount: child.val().amount,
                category: child.val().category,
                key: child.val().key,
                payer: child.val().payer,
                payment: child.val().payment,
                uid: child.val().uid
            },)
        });
    });
}, []);

console.log(list)

    return (
        <View>
        {list.map((i,k)=>{
            return(<Text key={k}>{i.amount}</Text>)
        })}

</View>
    )

}
```

I tried to print a list and expected it to work but it actually didn't show any output

Comment: You need to call `setList` to set a new list in state, see [React's documentation](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#adding-to-an-array) and the [linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676966/push-method-in-react-hooks-usestate). Also, it's important not to use indexes as keys in virtually all situations, [more here](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).