# Get array of Objects from form using useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js, react-hooks

So I'm working on this app that has a variable number of tabs, each tab has 3 fields (questionNumber, questionTitle, Answer), I would like to get the response in the form of

```json
    [{
    questionNumber: 1,
    questionTitle: "question 1",
    answer: "answer 1"
    },
    ...]
```

#### What I've tried

I created an empty list and then appended the object to it when the next button (button to navigate to the next question) is clicked, however on doing so, the list of objects gets reinitialized to the empty list, therefore I end up losing the data I had from the previous question

```js
const [quizData, setQuizData] = useState([]);
```

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: Take a look at useContext

Comment: Can you please provide what you have tried? Without context it will be difficult for anyone to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
const addResponse = (questionNumber, questionTitle, answer) => {
    const newResponse = {
      questionNumber,
      questionTitle,
      answer,
    };
    setQuizData([...quizData, newResponse]);
  };
```

Try adding a variable newResponse and then set the data into the state variable.

Comment: This is what I tried, however for some reason it does not work

Comment: @HimanshuSardana Check out this StackOverflow question: [Push method in React Hooks (useState)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677026/14499516)